# why does variable not multiply in print line

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python my school task was: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXJfA.png
I've done the other tasks really well but this one im struggling really bad. so far i've done this:

```
first_number = input('Enter first number')
second_number = input('Enter second number')
print(first_number ,'multiplied by '+second_number ,'is'+first_number*second_number)
```

and this is the error message i get:

```
 print(first_number ,'multiplied by '+second_number ,'is'+first_number*second_number)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

someone pls help!!!!

Comment: `first_number = int(input('Enter first number'))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the first_number and second_number to integers

```
first_number = int(input('Enter first number'))
second_number = int(input('Enter second number'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of return of the input function is String. Try to convert it to integer before multiply.

```
first_number = int( input('Enter first number'))
second_number = int( input('Enter second number'))
print(first_number,'multiplied by ',second_number,'is',first_number*second_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Values received from `input` are of type string.

If you want to apply math operations on input values, you should to convert them first to int.

Try:

```
first_number = int(input('Enter first number'))
second_number = int(input('Enter second number'))
print(f"{first_number} multiplied by {second_number} is {first_number*second_number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Input is stored as string, you must turn the variable into an integer:

```
first_number = int(input('Enter first number'))
second_number = int(input('Enter second number'))
```

Or use this code:

```
first_number = input('Enter first number')
second_number = input('Enter second number')
int(second_number)
int(first_number)
print(first_number ,'multiplied by '+second_number ,'is'+first_number*second_number)
```